# Java: Efficient Integer Color Darkening

Tags: java, performance, colors

So I am working on a program that requires darkening a color (represented in integer form) by a percentage. This process however I need to be relatively efficient; the process that I have already written works fine but I was wondering if I could refine this algorithm into something that is more effective but maintains a similar color.

The first algorithm I wrote while not terribly inefficient I felt as though there was room for improvement:
(The datatype for percentage is float, with a range of 0-1)

```
((int) (((color >> 16) & 0xFF) * percentage) << 16) | ((int) (((color >> 8) & 0xFF) * percentage) << 8) | ((int) (((color) & 0xFF) * percentage));
```

So I then refined this into something a little more efficient:

```
((int) ((color & 0xFF0000) * percentage) & 0xFF0000) | ((int) ((color & 0xFF00) * percentage) & 0xFF00) | ((int) (((color) & 0xFF) * percentage));
```

So as previously stated is there any way I could possibly refine this further, but also maintain a similar darkening effect this gives a color or is this about as efficient as I am able to get while maintaining the same effect? Thanks!

Comment: How "efficient" do you need this to be? Have you measured the performance of this, and determined it is a genuine performance bottleneck?

Comment: The reason I need this to be efficient is because I want to maintain a high fps, so it is not a bottleneck in the slightest but I want to make this algorithm as efficient as I can as to save fps for other resources.

Comment: "so it is not a bottleneck in the slightest" then stop fiddling. Revisit in the future when it is a performance issue.

Comment: Using fixed-point scaling is typically faster since it avoids two pretty expensive conversions per component

Comment: What is the datatype and value range of `percentage`?

Comment: The datatype of percentage is float and the range is 0-1, sorry should have mentioned that in the question.

Comment: integer arithemetic is faster. also, you may not like the results of using a percent. you may end up with a bunch of tables.

Comment: @RayTayek Thanks for the input on integer arithmetic that definitely sped up this algorithm a little, around a 15% increase in efficiency, also what did you mean by "may end up with a bunch of tables".

Comment: color can be complicated (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model). you might be better off by subtracting an amount (which would be faster) from each color. it may be different for each color. it might depend on the current value of the color (hence a table or matrix lookup). it all depends on whether the user likes what he sees when he darkens some color by some percent on some monitor.

Comment: I second Andy Turner; seeking performance for performance's sake is wasteful. Rather than trying to squeeze every inch out of every operation take a data-based approach and *benchmark* your application and eliminate *bottlenecks*. No amount of tuning this color algorithm will outweigh more serious (and common) issues like synchronization.